# Authentication dialog handle cancel click in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, iis

I have sharepoint online application. On login click I have written this:

```
<a href="/_windows/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=<%=Request.QueryString["Source"]%>">
```

I get a dialog box for the credentials. If I click cancel then I am getting this error:

```
Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.
```

Can you help me instead of this error, how can I redirect to home page? How can I handle cancel click event.

Note: I have to do in front end. I don't have access to code behind. Thanks

Comment: What type of application it is? Is this a front end of an InfoPath or Nintex Form?

Comment: It's a sharepoint online. I have tried setting custom errors in web.config, but it's not working